# How to access spring StateMachineConfig data

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I have a spring state machine that I configure with an `EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter` annotated with `@EnableStateMachineFactory`

It all goes well, I can create state machines using the factory:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
context.register(MyStateMachineConfig.class);
context.refresh();
StateMachineFactory stateMachineFactory = context.getBean(StateMachineFactory.class);
```

But I need to do some introspection on the configuration of the state machine. Basically I want to get a list of all the end states, for my record.

This information is available in `org.springframework.statemachine.config.StateMachineConfig` and I can tell when debugging that an instance of it is created. But it doesn't seem to be registered as a bean, and I can't access it as calling:

```
context.getBean(StateMachineConfig.class);
```

Causes:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.statemachine.config.StateMachineConfig<?, ?>' available
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register your own [`StateMachineModelVerifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/config/model/verifier/StateMachineModelVerifier.html) and access the States data - there's a public [`isEnd()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/config/model/StateData.html#isEnd--) method on the [StateData](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/api/org/springframework/statemachine/config/model/StateData.html) object.

```
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<States, Events> config)
        throws Exception {
    config
        .withVerifier()
            .enabled(true)
            .verifier(cusomVerifier());
}

@Bean    
public StateMachineModelVerifier customVerifier() {
  return new CustomVerifier();
}

class CustomVerifier extends DefaultStateMachineModelVerifier {
  @Override
  public void verify(StateMachineModel model) {
    super.verify(model); // call the existing sanity check model verifier
    Collection<StateData<State, Event> statesData = model.getStatesData().getStateData(); 
    //log your stuff
  }
}
```